# Automate the boring stuff with python madlibs program

Tags: python

I'm a beginner programmer so p;ease bear with me im doing this book and stuck on an exercise Directions are as follows
Mad Libs
Create a Mad Libs program that reads in text files and lets the user add
their own text anywhere the word ADJECTIVE, NOUN, ADVERB, or VERB
appears in the text file. For example, a text file may look like this:
The ADJECTIVE panda walked to the NOUN and then VERB. A nearby NOUN was
unaffected by these events.
The program would find these occurrences and prompt the user to
replace them.
Enter an adjective:
silly
Enter a noun:
chandelier
Enter a verb:
screamed
Enter a noun:
pickup truck
The following text file would then be created:
The silly panda walked to the chandelier and then screamed. A nearby pickup
truck was unaffected by these events.
The results should be printed to the screen and saved to a new text file.

```
import pyperclip

def ML(file):
Ofile=open(file)
x=Ofile.read()
y=x.split()
for i in range(len(y)):
    if y[i]=='ADJECTIVE':
        print('what is your adjective?')
        replacment=input()
        y[i]=replacment
        for i in range(len(y)):
            if y[i]=='NOUN':
                print('what is your noun?')
                replacment=input()
                y[i]=replacment
                for i in range(len(y)):
                    if y[i]=='VERB':
                        print('what is your verb?')
                        replacment=input()
                        y[i]=replacment
for i in range(len(y)):
    print(y[i],end=' ')
Nfile=open('madlibs3.txt.txt','w')
Nfile.write(x)
Nfile.close()
Ofile.close()
print('write your file path.')
Afile = input()
ML(Afile)
```

my problem is my code wont work

im pretty sure the main problem is the new string isn't being saved in the variable x however i dont understand how to do that

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  "my code won't work" is not a problem specification.  "i don't understand how to do that" is not a Stack Overflow issue, as this is not a coding or tutorial service.  Read the posting guidelines, and if you have a question under this site's charter, pleas edit your post to the applicable issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code as follows.

**Code**

```
def ML(input_file, output_file):
  # Use with since it automatrically closes files
  with open(input_file, 'r') as ifile, open(output_file, 'w') as ofile:
    result = []
    for line in ifile:  # looping through lines in file
      new_line = []
      for word in line.rstrip().split():  # looping through words in a line
        if word in ('NOUN', 'ADJECTIVE', 'VERB'):  # word is one of the ones we're checing for
          replace_word = input(f'What is your {word.lower()}?')
          new_line.append(replace_word)  # use replacement word
        else:
          new_line.append(word)          # use original word
      result.append(' '.join(new_line))  # form new space separated line

    # Write result
    ofile.write('\n'.join(result))       # join all lines together with carriage returns
                                         # and write to file

    return result                        # Return result to caller
```

**Usage**

```
print(ML('input.txt', 'output.txt'))     # print results to screen and
                                         # writes to 'output.txt'
```

Comment: thanks alot your code taught me alot as well as fixed my old code